# How to search numbers only linked to words in elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

How to make elastic return for request "bottles 200"  only bottles, not "glass 200". Now it processed numbers like words, sometimes it looks like numbers prioritized. Is it possible to bind numbers to words?

My settings

```php
'body' => [

    'settings' => [ 
        
        'analysis' => [ 
            "char_filter"=>[
                "ru"=>[
                    "type"=>"mapping",
                    "mappings"=>['Ё=>Е', 'ё=>е'],
                ],                           
            ],
            "analyzer"=>[
                "ru_RU_analizer"=>[
                    "tokenizer"=>"standard",
                    "filter"=>["stopwords_ru", "stop", "custom_word_delimiter", "lowercase", "ru_RU"],
                ],                               
            ],                            
            "filter"=>[
                "ru_RU"=>[
                "type"=>"hunspell",
                    "language"=>"ru_RU",
                ],                               
                "stopwords_ru"=>[
                    "type"=> "stop",
                    
                    "ignore_case"=>true
                ],
                "custom_word_delimiter"=>[
                    "type"=>"word_delimiter",
                    "generate_word_parts"=>true,
                    "generate_number_parts"=>true ,
                    "catenate_words"=>true,
                "catenate_numbers"=>false,
                    "catenate_all"=>true,  
                    "split_on_case_change"=>true,  
                    "preserve_original"=> true,  
                    "split_on_numerics"=>false,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Please, provide your query.

Comment: "must" =>[
                    [
                        'multi_match' => [
                            'query' =>  $query,
                            "fields" =>[
                                "tag^3",
                                 "name^2",
                                "description",
                                'code',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],

Comment: to help with the reproduction you need to provide some documents, and the mapping because I can't know which are the fields and their types and also which analyzer you use.